# Porque se iteran muchos componentes en React Js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, map

mi problema es, cuando quiero iterar un objeto en un componente de React, se iteran el componente princiapal

Asi se ve 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo cuando llamo el componente para agregarle los props

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="app container">
      {this.state.opciones.map((opcion, key) =>  
        <Preguntas
         item={opcion} key={key}
        />
      )}
      </div>
  );

  }
```

Este es el codigo del componente **Preguntas**

```
 render(){
        return(
            <div className="contenido">
            <div className="config-logo">
                <img src={LogoBoxi} />
            </div>
            <div className="cuestionario">       
                <input type="button" name={this.props.item.id} value={this.props.item.opcion} onClick={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="BotonesSeleccion">        
                <input type="button" value="Volver" />
                <input type="button" value="Siguiente" />
            </div>
        </div>

           );
        }
```

Comment: Según lo que muestras el resultado està bien. Con el map(), lo que haces es que por cada objeto del arreglo, devuelves un componente tipo Preguntas y esta bien. No entiendo que dices que está mal.

Answer (score 1):

Se muestra varias veces tu logo y los botones de abajo porque tienes esos tags dentro del map y se están duplicando, lo que puedes hacer extraer eso y ponerlo dentro de tu componente padre y entre tú logo y los botones de abajo iterar el componente Preguntas

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="app container">
      <div className="config-logo">
                <img src={LogoBoxi} />
            </div>
      {this.state.opciones.map((opcion, key) =>  
        <Preguntas
         item={opcion} key={key}
        />
      )}
     <div className="BotonesSeleccion">        
                <input type="button" value="Volver" />
                <input type="button" value="Siguiente" />
            </div> 
      </div>
  );

  }


render(){
        return(
            <div className="contenido">
            <div className="cuestionario">       
                <input type="button" name={this.props.item.id} value={this.props.item.opcion} onClick={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        </div>

           );
        }
```